# Composition isn't appearing on final animation render

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

[image: Compositing Nodes]

When I render the frames, the composition does not appear until I update something in the workflow:
[image]
[image]

So, when I render the entire animation, none of the frames is saving with the composition. What can I do?

Comment: can u pls provide the blend file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have ***Compositing*** switched off in your `Output Properties` tab. See here:

[image]